# Iterate through class fields and print them

Tags: c#

If I have for example one class like

```
public class User{
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Reputation { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastAccessDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
            public string WebSiteUrl { get; set; }
            public int Views { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public int UpVotes { get; set; }
            public int downVotes { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public string AboutMe { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to iterate through these fields dynamicly, for example to some method which will inspect passed object and it will return to caller its fields.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Alas the first result in Google for 'C# iterate class fields' is in fact a question on iterating through properties

Answer (score 74, accepted):

They're not fields, they're properties. You can use reflection to list them:

```
User user = ...
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in typeof(User).GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(user, null));
}
```