# how to represent instance of class as string without iterating through properties

Tags: c#

For debugging purposes I need to print all public fields/properties of certain class instance. Can I do that automatically somehow? Probably there are new feature in .NET 4.0? For example WPF DataGrid can do something like that.

This can be do manualy refer to this question [Iterate through class fields and print them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745224/iterate-through-class-fields-and-print-them) but I'm interesting if I can do that using some library method, instead of coding myself?

I.e. I want to replace this code:

```
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(ServerInfo).GetProperties())
        {
            result += prop.Name + " = " + prop.GetValue(si, null) + "\n";
        }
        foreach (FieldInfo prop in typeof(ServerInfo).GetFields())
        {
            result += prop.Name + " = " + prop.GetValue(si) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: The code available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6745255/870604) is really simple, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: What didn't you like in the answer?

Comment: Replace with something like what?

Comment: because I need to add fields at least and probably there are other public "things"? because it doesn't accept arbitrary instance but wrote for certain class, however probably I should just rewrite it to acceps any instance of class Class

Comment: @L.B. with something readable, one-line, accepting any instance of any class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're looking for better code. The code you have is just a few lines and looks fine to me.

If you want to modify the code that you have to work with any type, then that's simple:

```
string Format(object obj)
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
        result += prop.Name + " = " + prop.GetValue(obj, null) + "\n";
    }
    foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields())
    {
        result += field.Name + " = " + field.GetValue(obj) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Another thing that could be made better in this code is efficiency: you should use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `ToString` method of your custom classes and use an approach like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6745255/559144

or you create your own library / helper where you put the code at the link and for all classes you want to use it simply put a call to the helper method from the `ToString` overrides.

Not sure what you mean by WPF Datagrid can do that, are you sure you are not talking about the Visual Studio Debugger DataSet visualizer?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from Thomas:

```
User user = ...
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in typeof(User).GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(user, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aim for a simple list of properties to be displayed with WPF, maybe it would help using ListBox with ItemsSource "DataBound" to your object. In order to get a list of properties as strings from this object use some implementation of a IValueConverter, that reads the properties as described in the last few comments and put them in an IEnumerable.

When you're exchanging the object in the DataBinding, the new object is displayed immediately.

Comment: i just want to convert Object to String. I was talking about WPF because WPF can do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real better way than the code you've already written if you really are set on all properties and fields.  You can write an extension method and merge it into the System namespace, that way it'll appear on every instance of any type; I would also seriously consider using a `StringBuilder`, `AppendLine` and `string.Format`:

```
namespace System
{
  public static class MyExtensions
  {
    public static string Report<T>(this T instance)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())   
      {   
        sb.AppendLine(
          string.Format("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(si, null));   
      }   
      foreach (FieldInfo prop in typeof(T).GetFields())   
      {   
        sb.AppendLine(
          string.Format("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(si, null));   
      }   
      return sb.ToString(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Once you've written this you can simply do:

```
var instance = new ServerInfo();
var report = instance.Report();
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't handle the situation where a type's best representation is actually just a 'ToString' call - such as an `int` or `string` (string especially; since this code will simply output the `Length` member).

You mention the WPF datagrid - it's worth mentioning that that does not use reflection directly, instead it uses the `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` class - which is extensible and uses the `TypeConverter` mechanism to support conversion to/from strings (much better than simply relying on `ToString`).

However, it does not include fields in the metadata it produces; which you clearly want.

As a final note I would argue that this kind of thing should not be used a lot in programs; because very rarely does this level of detail actually matter.  Then there's the issue of how deep your report should go; for each member should you not actually be using `Report` again (in which case you have to either late-bind the generic or just write it to use `object` instead)?  But then you have nasty code for checking types that should be descended into or just `ToString`'d.  And if you start doing that you also need to take care not to recurse through cross-references; otherwise your report method could just lock up your application.

I would suggest instead that an interface is best:

```
public interface IReportable
{
  void Report(StringBuilder target);
}
```

Implementations of the interface then are restricted only to the types that you really need to report on; and you can use the extension method above, or one like it, as a default implementation on most of your types.  Crucially, however, a type can provide its own if it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

You could write extensions methods for the `Type` class:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static List<string> GetFieldsAndPropertiesAsString(this Type type)
    {
        return new List<string>(type.GetFieldsAsString().Union(type.GetPropertiesAsString()));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFieldsAsString(this Type type)
    {
        // Modify BindingFlags to get what you want (instance only, private/public...)
        foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        {
            yield return field.Name;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertiesAsString(this Type type)
    {
        // Modify BindingFlags to get what you want (instance only, private/public...)
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            yield return prop.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it using:

```
foreach (string zz in typeof(MyClass).GetFieldsAndPropertiesAsString())
{
    Console.WriteLine(zz);
}
```