# Iterate through all fields of an object in C# without Reflection

Tags: c#

I have a code that looks like this

```
if( evento.ObjetosUnity != null ) lista_elementos.AddRange( evento.ObjetosUnity.Cast<Elemento3DJS>() );
if( evento.Imagenes3D != null ) lista_elementos.AddRange( evento.Imagenes3D.Cast<Elemento3DJS>() );
if( evento.Botones != null ) lista_elementos.AddRange( evento.Botones.Cast<Elemento3DJS>() );
...and so on...
```

where I have to go through all the fields of an object. Is there an easier way of doing this?

**Edit:** I am compiling an App to iOS and CANT use Reflection.

Comment: I think [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.reflection.propertyinfo) is what you're looking for

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate through class fields and print them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745224/iterate-through-class-fields-and-print-them)

Comment: What are you using to compile your app? Because as far as I know, Xamarin.iOS allows you to use Reflection, just not for dynamic code generation (i.e. ``Reflection.Emit``).
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#System.Reflection.Emit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

Without reflection, you will have to spell it out. Want to use all fields? Write the code for it.